# How can I modify private variable that is returned by an objects getter?

Tags: javascript, oop

Here is what we have:

```
var MyObject = function(){
    var contents = [undefined,2,undefined,4,5];

    this.getContents = function(){
       return contents;
    }
}


var o = new MyObject();
```

As you understand, `o.getContents()` has the value of `[undefined,2,undefined,4,5]`

What I want to do is remove the undefined values of that private array, without overwriting the entire array, without making the private `contents` public, and without changing the objects code in general.

Comment: Your array contains only integers?

Comment: Just remove or also replace?

Comment: In that example yes, but the question is more generic. I discovered a way of modifying private properties of an object that are returned by a getter (similar to Javas `myObject.getProperty().value = 10;`) and wanted to share it. The reason I haven't accepted my answer, is because it is possible that someone has a better answer to this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, that was the approach I followed:

```
var MyObject = function(){
    var contents = [undefined,2,undefined,4,5];

    this.getContents = function(){
       return contents;
    }
}


   // Not extending the Array prototype is always a good idea
   var reIndex = function(){
   for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
   {
       //Remove this element from the array
       if(this[i] === undefined){
          this.splice(i, 1);
       }
   }

}


var o = new MyObject();

console.log(o.getContents()); //[undefined, 2, undefined, 4, 5]

reIndex.call(o.getContents());

console.log(o.getContents()); //[2, 4, 5]
```

Live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n2Cd3/)

Answer (score 2):

```js
return contents.filter(function(e) {return e});
```

This `filter` methods creates a new array while removing `""`, `null`, `undefined` and `0` values from the input array.

Comment: Isn't it more expensive to create an entire new array than making changes to the original one?

Comment: You could just do this: `return contents.filter(Number)`, Tada!

Comment: @Loupax The *problem* with yours is that it changes the `contents` private variable content too, since you're passing a reference of it to your `reindex` function.

Comment: That was the entire point. I wanted to change the contents of the private property but without rewriting the object code, for whatever reason that prevents me from doing so. Perhaps I didn't phrase the question well enough...